# Magento 2 Magnifier widget preview image issue

Tags: magento2, product-view, zoom

In Magento2 **MY_THEME/etc/view.xml** for the magnifier I've set the following values.

```
<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
    <var name="top">0</var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
    <var name="left">600</var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
    <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
    <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
    <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
    <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

So while on hover zoomed image should be shown beside of image but the zoomed image get clipped or not properly visible as shown in following picture.

Any ideas what can be wrong with it???

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify

```
<var name="top"></var> 
<var name="left"></var>
<var name="width">300</var>
<var name="height">300</var>
```